# PHP 7.2 Automatically enforcing callback prior to first byte transmission to Client

Tags: php

**PHP 7.2 :**
Is there a way to enforce "automatically" calling of a php function prior to the first byte that is sent out to the client?
(HTML Tags or anything)
Eg: `songs.php`:

```
// Please ignore spelling mistakes, and work on concept alone.
require_once('sessionSetup.php');
require_once('setup_Pre_HTML_Tag_Transmission_Enforcer.php');
// The above has a function called: doMyHTMLTags();

doMyStuff(); // Setups, validations
doMoreStuff();
doHTMLContentDisplay();

// I need to execute doMyHTMLTags(), if and when any of the functions starts sending out displayable text.
```

Example: If `doMoreStuff` does a `DIE('No resources')`; or if `doMyStuff` does a `{ echo 'unexpected issue'; exit; },` I still need my`doMyHTMLTags()` to be executed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome. Something like [`register_shutdown_function`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.register-shutdown-function.php)? It will be executed at the end though. If you want to do something at the very start every time, why not just do it first in your code?

Comment: Why is the PHP version relevant here? All in all this looks like an inappropriate software design.

Comment: Because each of the foregoing functions add more functionality that impacts the original function, and i don't want to do a combination of echo / call my function / die each time I want to force an abnormal path for display.
BTW: register_shutdown_function is equivalent to a __destructor in a static class.  Appreciate the answer, but that isn't it.
More concrete Eg: UI Developer makes a mistake which an underlying function catches the error.  I need to be able to use about criteria + IP based + charset based: printing backtrace / sending emails / add future functionalities @ a central locn.

Answer (score 1):

Didn't try it, but maybe [ob_start](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) would do the trick:

```
ob_start(
    function($buffer) {
        // nothing was produced
        if (strlen($buffer) === 0) {
            return false;
        }

        // prepend our string
        return doMyHTMLTags() . $buffer;
    }
);

doMyStuff(); // Setups, validations
doMoreStuff();
doHTMLContentDisplay();
```

If `doMyHTMLTags()` doesn't return string, but it is printing it to the browser, you can try this (but it will always call `doMyHTMLTags`):

```
// get our string from output
ob_start();
doMyHTMLTags();
$my_html_tags = ob_get_clean();

ob_start(
    function($buffer) use ($my_html_tags) {
        // nothing was produced
        if (strlen($buffer) === 0) {
            return $buffer;
        }

        // prepend our string
        return $my_html_tags . $buffer;
    }
);

doMyStuff(); // Setups, validations
doMoreStuff();
doHTMLContentDisplay();
```